# Where is WindowsDefaultLocation (CW_USEDEFAULT)?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to find out how OS defines so called WindowsDefaultLocation in Winforms. The forms have property called StartPosition that takes enumeration as value. One the values is WindowsDefaultLocation (= 2). In framework code I found:

```
public enum FormStartPosition
```

The comment to enum:

```
WindowsDefaultLocation = 2;
```

is

> The form is positioned at the Windows default location and has the bounds determined by Windows default.

In method that sets form's position (for WindowsDefaultLocation) I found:

```
cp.X = NativeMethods.CW_USEDEFAULT;
cp.Y = NativeMethods.CW_USEDEFAULT;
```

where

```
CW_USEDEFAULT = (unchecked((int)0x80000000))
```

Other enums (eg: CenterScreen) have inside some mathematical calculations - it's understandable.

```
cp.X = Math.Max(clientRect.X, clientRect.X + (clientRect.Width - cp.Width)/2);
cp.Y = Math.Max(clientRect.Y, clientRect.Y + (clientRect.Height - cp.Height)/2);
```

So my question again: where is Windows default location for newly created form and how does OS define it each time when application starts or/and new form is initialized and shown?

Comment: This link might give some insight in how Windows decides "as it existed in an unspecified version of Windows": https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121126-00/?p=5993

Comment: The default location can also be changed by the program that spawned yours by calling CreateProcess.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: Nice. I was still looking for that link.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: Please promote your comment to an answer so i will accept it. The article in provided link answers my question in 100%. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The position is determined by the OS, and the implementation of that algorithm might differ from one OS version to the other.

Raymond Chen explains the rules for "an unspecified version of Windows" at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121126-00/?p=5993

Basically if there is no other reason for a specific monitor (such as a parent window), the window will be placed on the primary monitor, and the location on that monitor will be at an offset of the previous default location.